# Issue with perl -MCPAN -e 'install Module::Build';

Tags: centos, perl

While doing the perl -MCPAN -e 'install Module::Build'; it gives the following error, How can I resolve it ?

```
/usr/bin/perl Build --makefile_env_macros 1
Can't locate Perl/OSType.pm in @INC (@INC contains: t/lib t/bundled lib /usr/lib64/perl5/site_perl/5.8.8/x86_64-linux-thread-multi /usr/lib/perl5/site_perl/5.8.8 /usr/lib/perl5/site_perl /usr/lib64/perl5/vendor_perl/5.8.8/x86_64-linux-thread-multi /usr/lib/perl5/vendor_perl/5.8.8 /usr/lib/perl5/vendor_perl /usr/lib64/perl5/5.8.8/x86_64-linux-thread-multi /usr/lib/perl5/5.8.8 .) at lib/Module/Build.pm line 13.
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
Can't locate Perl/OSType.pm in @INC
```

Open the [`Build.pm`](http://cpansearch.perl.org/src/LEONT/Module-Build-0.4002/lib/Module/Build.pm) file, you will see something like this:

```perl
use Perl::OSType ();
```

and this module isn't installed. So, try this:

```
# yum install perl-Perl-OSType.noarch
```

Answer (score 2):

What's wrong with using the module provided by CentOS?

```
yum install perl-Module-Build
```

Come to think of it, the perl module that you *really* want (you didn't specify what it is) is probably already in the repositories, too.

Comment: x2 - Using the package management for modules is definitely easier over time.  CPAN is great, but life will be easier if you handle versions and upgrades in a single place.